# Block diagram with child on one of its node

Tags: diagrams, block

I've been learning to use LaTeX for my final project at campus. And now, I get into flowchart-making section. I could make a simple block diagram, like input-output process but I find my self in trouble when I try to make a harder one. One of them is shown as below.[image]

---

Would you help me to figure this thing out? any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here's my simple code diagram that I made and I guess it's still wrong

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,arrows}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle, draw, text width=15mm, text centered, 
minimum height=4em}, line/.style={draw, -latex'}}
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=30mm, sibling distance=30mm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=30mm, sibling distance=15mm]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=20mm]
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right,->,>=angle 60]
%\begin{scope}[yshift=0]
\node [block] {Datang}
child {node [block] {Loket 3 Fasilitas Pelayanan Tahap 1}
    child {node[block]{Loket 3 Fasilitas Pelayanan Tahap 2}
        child[-] {node{}}  
    }
}
child {node[block] {Loket 2 Fasilitas Pelayanan Tahap 1}
child {node[block]{Loket 2 Fasilitas Pelayanan Tahap 2}
    child[-] {node{}}  
}
}
child {node[block] {Loket 1 Fasilitas Pelayanan Tahap 1}
    child {node[block]{Loket 1 Fasilitas Pelayanan Tahap 2}
        child[-] {node{}}  
    }
};


%\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle, draw, text width=15mm, text centered, 
minimum height=4em}, line/.style={draw, -latex'}}
\tikzset{level 1/.style={level distance=30mm, sibling distance=30mm},
level 2/.style={level distance=30mm, sibling distance=15mm},
level 3/.style={level distance=20mm}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right,->,>=angle 60]
\node [block] {Datang}
child {node [block] {Loket 3 Fasilitas Pelayanan Tahap 1}
    child {node[block] (C1){Loket 3 Fasilitas Pelayanan Tahap 2}
    }
}
child {node[block] {Loket 2 Fasilitas Pelayanan Tahap 1}
child {node[block] (C2) {Loket 2 Fasilitas Pelayanan Tahap 2}
}
}
child {node[block] {Loket 1 Fasilitas Pelayanan Tahap 1}
    child {node[block] (C3) {Loket 1 Fasilitas Pelayanan Tahap 2}
    }
};
\node[block,right=1.5cm of C2] (D1) {final node};
\foreach \X in {1,2,3}
{\draw (C\X) -- (D1);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]